# Django- Problems with like/follow button's

Tags: python, django

I want to create a like/follow system on user posts.

Due to many users being able to like a post and users being able to like many posts I made 2 separate models.

Models.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
user= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.TextField()
content = models.TextField()
date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
last_modified = models.DateTimeField(_('Last Edited'), auto_now=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)

class Question_Follows(models.Model): 
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):

model = Question
slug  = 'slug'
template_name = "questions/question_detail.html" 


 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(QuestionDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['now'] = timezone.now()

    #obj= Question_Follows.objects.filter(id=question.id)
    #context['follow_count'] = Question_Follows.objects.filter(id='question.id')
    #obj.count <----- none of these have worked so far.


    return context
```

detailview.html:

```
<div id="question_container">
<input type='hidden' id="{{ object.id }}" name="id">  <--- tried this as a way to get question id -->
<h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ object.content }}</p>
<p>Published: {{ object.date_published|date }}</p>
<p>Date: {{ now |date }}</p>

<button class="follow"><span id='follow-span'>Follow| <strong id='follow-count'>{{ follow_count }}</strong> </button>
</span></button>
```

I'm having problems 'collecting' the right question once the like button has been pressed and also showing the right number of likes for the question i.e the follow count for each question.

Comment: You've listed your template as 'detailview.html', but in your view code you've specified `"questions/question_detail.html" ` as your template name. Which is it? Also, in your detailview.html, you've said you tried to get the object id via `{{object.id}}`. That looks like it should work to me. What do you get there?

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. If I'm understanding your intention properly, you should not need `count = models.IntegerField(default=0)` on the `Question_Follows` model. A new row is created in the database table for this model every time a user follows a question. Can a user follow the same question more than once? If not, then you don't need a count field.
2. The number of follows for the question should be available in the view using something like:

   def get_context_data(self, kwargs):

   ```
   context = super(QuestionDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
   context['now'] = timezone.now()
   context['follow_count'] = self.object.follows.count()
   return context
   ```

Note that you'll need to add a related name to your foreign key, so it will be  `question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follows')` for this to work.

3. It's conventional to name Django models in CamelCase (no underscores), and in singular form - so `Question_Follows` would be `QuestionFollow`.

See my comment for further questions related to your template issues - I suspect you are just using the wrong template file name.

Comment: Sorry, code formatting appears to be borked - no idea why

Comment: Hay, thanks for the answer. The html name above is just a type, the file is actually called question_detail.html. I'm just trying your solution now, I'll let you know how it goes.